# Complex conditional element in accumulate in Jess rules

Tags: rules, protege, jess

I am trying to find average value of temperature observations in JessTab which requires joining facts from multiple classes. The following rule:

```
(defrule averageOfObsValue  
?res <- 
(accumulate  
    (progn (bind ?s 0)(bind ?n 0)) 
    (progn (bind ?s (+ ?s ?v)) (++ ?n)) 
    (create$ ?n ?s ?qo) 
    (and  
        (object (is-a http..#ObservationValue) 
                (OBJECT ?ov)
                (http..#hasDataValue ?v)
        )
        (object (is-a http..#SensorOutput) 
                (OBJECT ?so) 
                (http..#hasValue ?ov)
        )
        (object (is-a http..#Observation)
                (OBJECT ?o)
                (http..#observationResult ?so)
                (http..#qualityOfObservation ?qo)
        )   
    )
)
=>  
(bind ?q (nth$ 3 ?res))  
(bind ?s (nth$ 2 ?res))  
(bind ?n (nth$ 1 ?res))  
(if (= (?q getURI) "http..#Temperature") then
(printout t "Average value is " (/ ?s ?n) " of " ?n " temperature observations." crlf)))
```

in the WM has the following form:

```
(defrule MAIN::averageOfObsValue 
   (or 
     (and 
       (object (is-a http..#ObservationValue) 
               (OBJECT ?ov) 
               (http..#isValueOf ?so) 
               (http..#hasDataValue ?v))) 
     (and 
       (object (is-a http..#SensorOutput) 
               (OBJECT ?so) (http..#isObservationResultOf ?o))) 
     (and 
       (object (is-a http..#Observation) 
               (OBJECT ?o) (http..#qualityOfObservation ?qo)))) 
   => 
   (bind ?q (nth$ 3 ?res)) 
   (bind ?s (nth$ 2 ?res)) 
   (bind ?n (nth$ 1 ?res)) 
   (if (= (?q getURI) "http..#Temperature") then
   (printout t "Average value is " (/ ?s ?n) " of " ?n " temperature observations." crlf)))
```

and while running it the following error appears:

> Jess reported an error in routine Context.getVariable
>       while executing (nth$ 3 ?res)
>       while executing (bind ?q (nth$ 3 ?res))
>       while executing defrule MAIN::averageOfObsValue655
>       while executing (run).
>     Message: No such variable res.
>     Program text: ( run )  at line 137.

Comment: There is a rather obvious syntax error in the line `(progn (bind ?s 0)(bind ?n 0)` - no closing parenthesis.

Comment: @laune I fixed that and modified the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems (and your latest observation confirms it) that accumulate cannot be applied to a CE with a conjunction. The best way is to create temporary facts containing the values over which the average needs to be computed, *but care must be taken to create distinct temporary fact*.

```
(deftemplate Value (slot v)(slot s)

(defrule createValueFacts
    (declare (salience 100))
    (object (is-a http..#ObservationValue) 
            (OBJECT ?ov)
            (http..#hasDataValue ?v)
    )
?s<-(object (is-a http..#SensorOutput) 
            (OBJECT ?so) 
            (http..#hasValue ?ov)
    )
    (object (is-a http..#Observation)
            (OBJECT ?o)
            (http..#observationResult ?so)
            (http..#qualityOfObservation ?qo)
    )
=>
    (assert (Value (v ?v)(s ?s))   ; using slot s to make fact unique
)
```

These `Value` facts can be easily accumulated:

```
(defrule averageOfObsValue 
?res <- (accumulate  
    (progn (bind ?s 0)(bind ?n 0)) 
    (progn (bind ?s (+ ?s ?v)) (++ ?n)) 
    (create$ ?n ?s) 
    (Value (v ?v)))
=>
(bind ?s (nth$ 2 ?res))  
(bind ?n (nth$ 1 ?res))  
(printout t "Average value is " (/ ?s ?n) " of " ?n " temperature observations." crlf))
```

Comment: In RBS, there may be a mode for the Engine where duplicate facts are automatically deleted. Not sure whether Jess has this mode, and how it is (de)activated. I haven't found a reference to this in the Jess documentation. Apparently it is the unmodifiable default behaviour. - Adding a note to my A.

Comment: Thanks it works :). But, only distinct v values are asserted on WM, since same values overwrite each other and thus the average value is not correct. Any idea how to solve this...

Comment: I've just added s.th. to my A. I'm not sure what is unique in the triplet of your facts; if necessary add another slot. -- A fact is a "truth" and it can't be repeated in Jess - it doesn't become any truer.

Comment: An alternative approach would be to accumulate the values into a singe fact. In that case, don't insert but modify and use no-loop to avoid looping. Needs a first high-salience rule to create the sum with its slot set to zero.

Comment: I used the URI as per unique value of new slot and it gives the result. Thanks again for the quick responses